# Error connecting to SQL Server from Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, database-connection, razor-pages

I am trying to convert my very basic website from straight HTML to Razor Pages. My main resources have been Adam Freeman and Mike Brind. So far I have created a small foundation and now am trying to run a query against my database in Index.cshtml. If I comment out the query, the application will compile and run (that is to say it will display the home page). When I try to include the query I get a runtime error when trying to load the home page:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Cannot open database "Alpha" requested by the login. The login failed.

InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.

Alpha.Pages.Pages_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
@foreach (YearSummary s in Model.YearSummaries) {

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
An error occurred using the connection to database 'Alpha' on server '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Alpha.Data.AlphaContext'.

I'm assuming this has something to do with my connection string.

**appsettings.json**
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
"AlphaConnection": "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Alpha;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}

**Program.cs**
builder.Services.AddDbContext(options => {
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AlphaConnection"));
});

**Index.cshtml**
@foreach (YearSummary s in Model.YearSummaries) {

I've played around with the connection string, with no luck. I really don't know where to go from here.

I have uploaded my code to GitHub: https://github.com/JB45424/Alpha

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated the database after the database migration? If the database is not updated, problems like this can occur.

I cloned your code and ran it directly and I also encountered your error. But after I install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` NuGet package and run the following commands to migrate and update the database, the program works fine:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

Helpful link: [Test the Asp.Net Core MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#test-the-app).

Test Result:
[image]

Is this the effect of your page loading normally?

Comment: Outstanding. Yes, that is what the page is supposed to look like. I will implement your directions when I am back at my computer and will advise back. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes! That resolved my problem and I can resume development. Greatly appreciated!